# Having trouble with XML file opening in browser even though I have an XSL file too

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

When I open the following XML in Chrome, only the tree displays and a message that says "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

XML: 
[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18VPV.png)

XSL: 
[XSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7rIx.png)

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Please post your code **as code** - not as images or links to images.

Comment: Both files seem to be XSLT stylesheets. Usually you have one XML document referencing a second XML document which is an XSLT stylesheet using `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>`. But most browsers up to date browsers support that anymore when loading from the local file system.